# Drag and drop multiple files with separate input tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

Alot of code, for this example, but the point is:

I'm modifying a plugin written in PHP and javascript. I'm generating a bunch of input fields and javascript is creating a drag and drop functionality.

It works ok for single files each time. (Drag and drop 1 file on the section for dropping files, and repeat)

But it is not working for multiple files, because they end up in 1 input field (when adding "multiple" attribute to input elements)

Basically the line:

```
document.querySelector('.file-input-element'+j).files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
```

This line sets the value to a file or multiple files, it is an object of type: FileList.

But I can't manage to get the javascript code to split this object, is it impossible? Anyway if someone can help me with this that would be nice. Sort of stuck on this.

To summarize: I need to drag and drop multiple files (images) and get them into separate input elements.

```
<style>
    #drop_zone {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px dotted red;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function dropHandler(ev) {
        console.log('File(s) dropped');

        // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
        ev.preventDefault();

        if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
            // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
                    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                        console.log(document.querySelector('.file-input-element'+j).files.length == 0);
                        if (document.querySelector('.file-input-element'+j).files.length == 0) {
                            // console.log(j+" is leeg dus vullen");
                            document.querySelector('.file-input-element'+j).files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
                            break; 
                        }
                    }

        } else {
            // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
            for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
    function dragOverHandler(ev) {
        console.log('File(s) in drop zone'); 

        // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
<div class="fieldset marketplace-image">
    <h4 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Images'); ?></h4>
    <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
        <p>Drag one or more files to this Drop Zone ...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="marketplace_image_list">
        <?php for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
            <div class="market_place_add_image<?=$i;?>">
                <input class="file-input-element<?=$i;?>" type="file" name="image[<?=$i;?>][]">
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My be you need to refer to `ev.dataTransfer.items[j]` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList/DataTransferItem] instead of  `ev.dataTransfer.files` for each input